# Can't set checkbox DataValidation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

I've tried to automatically add checkboxes as dataValidation. Checked is 1, unchecked is 0. 
If I'm trying to set it up manually - everything working fine. When I'm trying to use some string like `'Approved'` as default - it is working too. I've tried to use `'true'` string and got the same issue. If I'm trying to modify validation manually - everything is correct in Data Validation window, and then I'm pressing 'OK' (without any changes) - issue is gone.

Sample code:

```
function make_checkboxes(){
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveRange();
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox(1, 0).build();
    cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run function on any range
2. Check the checkbox - checkbox is dissapeared, cell value is 1 and "Invalid:This cell's contents violate its validation rule"

---

When I've tried to find a workaround and just copy the validation (from script) I've got an error:

> "Message details
>   Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id 1UWvTC3mswQ0lh23eZDq49lr2VNeQ8tEMrzlpF0Kv07c."

Sample code:

```
var range = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('hacks_and_workarounds').getRange('A1');
valid_rule = range.getDataValidation();
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().setDataValidation(valid_rule);
```

Comment: Definitely some unexpected results there.  There is an issue similar to this [151242193](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151242193)

Comment: @Cooper - able to reproduce myself. The validation expects a *plaintext* format of the cell (testing showed that 1.0 or 0.0 are returned as type `string`). I don't understand *why*, but this might be a documentation mishap, will add an answer

Comment: I found that using TRUE and FALSE caused problems which is what the values are if you use insertCheckBox method from the menu. I also found that using "1" and "0" would not work either.  The signature for the  requireCheckBox methold was [Object, Objectt](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requireCheckbox(Object,Object)) which I find difficult to understand

Comment: @Cooper - I also found the spec confusing, but it had a simpler explanation - the d.ts file has `requireCheckbox` declared with `any` type, which most likely got converted to `Object` in docs. Although I agree that this is not an excuse to have a different actual contract than advertised.
Will check for TRUE / FALSE, but I suspect the same goes for both of them

Comment: It clearly does not accept boolean primitives or numbers.

Comment: @Cooper The only workaround (tested) I see for now is to change the number format of the cell to "plaintext". Although I think the method *does* accept boolean primitives and numbers - no errors of signature mismatch (while other methods do have such validation I suspect that this one should also have one), something seems to be screwed up in the method logic itself (or we are missing an elephant in the room - I never saw any type restriction imposed on parameters of the method)

Answer (score 3):

**Problem**

Checkbox `DataValidation` with numeric constraints results in "Invalid: This cell's contents violate its validation rule" error.

**Explanation & testing**

I decided to reproduce the issue and replicated the same [`DataValidation`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation) builder on a sample spreadsheet (no formats set, validations cleared, etc). The issue was successfully reproduced, but what caught my eye was the output of a `getCriteriaValues()` method. To test, I used the following function:

```
function getDataValidation() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

    const cell = sh.getActiveCell();

    const dataValidation = cell.getDataValidation();

    const allowed = dataValidation.getCriteriaValues();

    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

    ui.alert(`Allowed values: ${allowed.join(", ")}, type: ${typeof allowed[0]}`);
}
```

The output stated:

> Allowed values: 1.0, 0.0, type: string

Note the type of value (one would expect it to be a `number`). I added a small utility for checking what are the current value, display value and number format for a given cell.

Here is the utility used (for reference):

```
function getCellValueDataType() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
    const cell = sh.getActiveCell();

    const value = cell.getValue();

    const display = cell.getDisplayValue();

    const format = cell.getNumberFormat();

    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

    const valuePrompt = `The value is "${value} of type ${typeof value}"`;
    const displayPrompt = `Display value is "${display}" of type ${typeof display}`;

    ui.alert(`${valuePrompt}\n${displayPrompt}\nFormat is ${format}`);
}
```

Here is the output if the format is set to *automatic* (which is the default):

```
The value is "1 of type number"
Display value is "1" of type string
Format is 0.###############
```

And here is how it looks like for the *plaintext* format:

```
The value is "1.0 of type string"
Display value is "1.0" of type string
Format is
```

Compare it to the output of `getCriteriaValues()` - we obviously need to change the number format to plaintext to match. Upon doing so, the error, as expected, goes away, and the checkbox starts to work properly:

[image: checkbox animation]

Same goes for `true` and `false` - only when the cell format is set to plaintext does the validation recognize the value as correct:

```
The value is "true of type string"
Display value is "true" of type string
Format is
```

**Solution**

If you want to set correct format programmatically, you can use the [`setNumberFormat`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat) (or its batch equivalent) with `"@"` parameter (forces content to be set as plaintext):

```
rng.setNumberFormat("@"); //assuming rng is defined elsewhere
```

**Notes**

1. I don't know *why* it works the way it does. You are correct in assuming that any value should go as the documentation states that parameter type is `any` (check the TS declaration file, for example).
2. [Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper) linked to a related issue [reported to issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151242193) - at the time of writing, unfortunately, the report didn't get any traction and got closed (likely due to inactivity), and then updated to "won't fix".

**References**

1. `requireCheckbox()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requireCheckbox(Object))
2. `getCriteriaType()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#getcriteriatype)
3. `getNumberFormat()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumberformat)
4. `getDisplayValue()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue)

Comment: The reported issue is marked as Won't Fix (obsolete).

Comment: @Rubén yeah, thanks - included the update in the answer! I wonder why they closed it as  obsolete, though - haven't done GAS in a while, has something changed making it so?

Comment: I not aware of a relevant change regarding checkboxes in Google Apps Script... By the way, I came to this answer because I'm looking for a canonical Q/A for questions using the wrong datatype when comparing the checkbox value. Any suggestion?